# Azure blob trigger dynamic path not working

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I'm using Capture event to retrieve event from Eventhub to storage container. but In capture event I chosen  blob file path format as

```
{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}
```

now how to give dynamic blob path in blog trigger.

i written as following

```
@FunctionName("AzureBlogTriggerFn5")
    public void blobHandler(
            @BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "uts-blobcontainer-nb-dev/uts-eventhubns/uts-nb-eventhub/{partition}/{yyyy}/{MM}/{dd}/{HH}/{mm}/{ss}/{fileName}", dataType = "binary", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") byte[] content,
            @BindingName("fileName") String fileName,
            final ExecutionContext context
    ) throws StorageException, IOException, URISyntaxException, InvalidKeyException, InterruptedException {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Blob trigger function processed a blob. Name: " + fileName + "\n  Size: " + content.length + " Bytes");
```

i'm getting following error

```
**2019-12-19T15:05:52.576 [Error] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.DecompressServiceFunctionNB'. System.Private.CoreLib: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: mm.**
```

**please suggest me, how to give dynamic path for partitionId, year, month, day,hour,minutes,seconds in blogtrigger in Azure ?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is because of having both "MM" and "mm".

When using [trigger blob name patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=java#trigger---blob-name-patterns), the keys can be any string. In your case, something like this should work instead

```
path = "uts-blobcontainer-nb-dev/uts-eventhubns/uts-nb-eventhub/{partitionId}/{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/{minute}/{second}/{fileName}"
And bind the ones you require in your function.
```